# JavaScript objects in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, web-sql, node-webkit

Here is an excerpt from a Node Webkit WebSQL wrapper I'm building and I'm running into a problem. See the `<----` line below.

`get_columns` is a simple JavaScript array:

```
['id','group_name','description']
```

But when they come out of the database the object (a.k.a. `results.rows.item(i)`):

```
{'description','group_name','id'}
```

Is this because the browser or JavaScript wants to sort all objects in alphabetical order?

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    var sql = 'SELECT ' + get_columns + ' FROM ' + table;
    tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx, results) {
        if (results.rows.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                _data.push(results.rows.item(i)); // <---- columns from WebSQL are in alphabetical order, so not cool. 
            }
        }
        deferred.resolve(_data);
    });
});
```

My thoughts are to process the object and put the values of the object into my array as values for each key.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: So my hunch is correct then. I'll have to interpret the resulting object and do a 1:1 matching on expected columns and assign values.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If it's an object anyway, you are going to access it by property names. Or do you want to push an array for each row to `_data`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify` with the results as the first parameter and the array as a second parameter to enforce the order:

```
function foo(get_columns)
  {
  var results = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3};

  _data = JSON.stringify(results, get_columns);
  return _data;
  }

foo(['c','a','b'])
```

**References**

- [ECMAScript Wiki: JSON Support](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:json_support)